# CoinMarketCapApi get all coins with their logos

Tags: cryptocurrency, cryptoapi, coinmarketcap

I want to display a list of all cryptocurrencies with their logos.
I tried to call CoinMarketCap API to get these informations.
I found this endpoint **/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest** that return all coins but without logos.
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

There is another endpoint **/v2/cryptocurrency/info** that return the logo, but not for all coins.
I should specify a list of coins to get their logos.
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyInfo

I think that getting all coins from the first endpoint, and pass them as parameters in the second endpoint is not a good idea.

My questions are:
is there another way to get coins with their logo without making two API calls?
is the CoinMarketCap API, the best api to get these informations or I should search for another API?

[image: example of /v2/cryptocurrency/info response]